# Assign number to each unique date in R

Tags: r

I have a column with date values. I am trying to mark the most recent date as 1 and the most recent-before as 2 and so on.
Here I am using `dplyr` to achive this, but after executing the code I am getting constant outcome as '1'

```
date = c("2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-01-23","2020-01-24")
df = as.data.frame(date)
df$date= as.Date(df$date)

max_date=max(df$date)
min_date =min(df$date)

ll <- seq(min_date, max_date, by = "day")

df$day_no = case_when(
  ( max(df$date) ==as.Date(ll[5])) ~ as.integer(1),
  ( max(df$date)-1 ==as.Date(ll[4])) ~ as.integer(2),
  ( max(df$date)-2 ==as.Date(ll[3])) ~ as.integer(3),
  ( max(df$date)-3 ==as.Date(ll[2])) ~ as.integer(4),
  ( max(df$date)-4 ==as.Date(ll[1])) ~ as.integer(5),
  TRUE ~ as.integer(NA)
  )
```

The output I am looking for is as below:

```
day_no = c(5,4,3,2,1)
day_no = as.integer(day_no)
df = data.frame(date,day_no)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using `xxx_rank` in dplyr or `rank` in base r.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(day_no = dense_rank(desc(date)))
```

just pick the one works for your dataset.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann sorry i should stated clearly. I mean there are many `rank` varaitions in dplyr like `dense_rank`,`min_rank`

Comment: If I were a beginner with R, `xxx_rank` would be utterly misleading. Also, you mention `rank` but you don't show how to use it.

Comment: Be careful with rank if you may have dates more than once in your data e.g. `date <- c("2020-01-20","2020-01-19","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-01-23","2020-01-24", "2020-01-22")`
. I think transforming to factor is more robust in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, use `rank`:

```
df$daterank <- rank(df$date)
df
        date daterank
1 2020-01-20        1
2 2020-01-21        2
3 2020-01-22        3
4 2020-01-23        4
5 2020-01-24        5
```

Alternatively, if you require inversed ranking, add `-` and convert dates to numeric:

```
df$daterank <- rank(- as.numeric(df$date))
df
        date daterank
1 2020-01-20        5
2 2020-01-21        4
3 2020-01-22        3
4 2020-01-23        2
5 2020-01-24        1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem, convert the dates to their integer representation, then subtract the maximum. To subtract `1L` adjusts for the values of the expected output. Then convert to absolute values.

```
df$day_no <- abs(as.integer(df$date) - max(as.integer(df$date)) - 1L)
df
#        date day_no
#1 2020-01-20      5
#2 2020-01-21      4
#3 2020-01-22      3
#4 2020-01-23      2
#5 2020-01-24      1
```

Comment: alternatively, you could transform it to a factor and then use the numeric representation of the factor.`date <- c("2020-01-20","2020-01-19","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-01-23","2020-01-24", "2020-01-22")`

`as.numeric(factor(date))`